# Reverse Linked List Recursively without using any new variable

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, reverse

In a job interview I was asked to write a function in C that recursively reverses a linked list, returns the new first node, and doesn't use any new nodes.

How can you do this?

Comment: I've rolled back because the edit changed the question too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the general idea, in an agnostic language with C-like syntax:

```
Node invert(Node list, Node acc) {
    if (list == null)
        return acc;
    Node next = list.next;
    list.next = acc;
    return invert(next, list);
}
```

The above function receives the first node of the list to be inverted and the accumulated value so far, and returns the head of the newly-inverted list - the reversal of nodes is done in-place, no extra space is allocated (besides a local variable in the stack). Call it like this:

```
invert(firstNodeOfList, null);
```

This is an example of a tail recursion: the result gets collected in the `acc` parameter, and when each recursive call returns, there's nothing left to do, just return the accumulated value.

**UPDATE:**

In a functional language it's easier and more natural to write a function to reverse a list without using a local variable, for instance look at the following code in Scheme - it has drawback, that it will create a new list node when calling the `cons` procedure:

```
(define (invert lst acc)
  (if (empty? lst)
      acc
      (invert (rest lst)
              (cons (first lst) acc))))

(invert '(1 2 3 4 5) '())
> '(5 4 3 2 1)
```

Bottom line: you either create a new node or create a new local variable at each recursive call, but unless the programming language offers an expression for sequential execution and the compiler guarantees evaluation order (see @WillNess' answer) you can't eliminate both and have a working algorithm. Better play it safe and use a temporary variable for enforcing evaluation order and always obtaining correct results.

Comment: Your recursive call should be `invert(next, list)` right?  Pretty similar to what I came up with.

Comment: @SumuduFernando you're right, that was a typo. Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: but aren't you define a new node after the if statement ?

Comment: @user1120007 not at all, I'm just storing an existing node reference in a local variable

Comment: but that's mean that in every activation frame there is a new variable, when i asked if i can do this they said no .

Comment: @user1120007 there is a new variable in each activation frame, but not a new _node_, because the variable simply points to an existing node. In your question you state that the solution must not use any new nodes, and that requirement is met. In Java, you can't write a solution to this problem without the extra variable. In C/C++ maybe, at the price of using some pointer tricks

Comment: you could use `(let ((r (cdr lst))) (set-cdr! lst acc) (invert r lst))` instead of the `cons` form. You could just replace the `cons` form with `(begin (set-cdr! lst acc) lst)` if the argument's evaluation order was left-to-right instead of unpecified. I think in C it is left-to-right. This means changing your C function to `{if (!lst) return acc; return invert(lst.next, ((lst.next=acc),lst));}`.

Comment: apparently, not. some C compilers do, some don't. I've added an answer, with link to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple: recurse to the end of the list, passing in the new `next` pointer each time and returning the end of the list.

```
struct list {
    struct list *next;
};

struct list *reverse(struct list *cur, struct list *prev) {
    struct list *next = cur->next;
    cur->next = prev;
    if(next == NULL) return cur;
    return reverse(next, cur);
}

reverse(head, NULL);
```

Comment: but by using "struct list *next" aren't you define a new node ?

Comment: No, this only declares a pointer to a node. `malloc` would create a new node.

Comment: but you are still saving it on the stack instead on the heap .

Comment: the interviewr cunfused my , he said no extra space at all so i thgout pointer take up space, turn out i didn't understand him .

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what a "recursively linked list" is so I'll go with your title and assume you want to "reverse a linked list" using a recursive function.

I'll assume it's a singly linked list (so each element has a single pointer `next` to the next element) and by convention take `next = NULL` for the last element.  <del>For doubly linked lists you have to also deal with the `prev` pointers but it is basically the same idea.</del>  With a doubly linked list it is simpler since you don't even need to keep track of the previous element; you just have to flip the two pointers around on each element.

To reverse the list we can imagine walking down it an element at a time, flipping the `next` pointers to point to the previous element as we go.  This is easy enough to write as a recursive function which takes as parameters a pointer to the current element and a pointer to the previous element (at the start this pointer is `NULL`).

```
node* reverseList(node* head, node* prev = NULL) {
  if (head == NULL) return prev;

  std::swap(head->next, prev); // prev points to next element to process
  return reverseList(prev, head);
}
```

Comment: i didn't think he meant that i can use external function because he said it could be in java and i need to write one function, he also gave my a hint that it would be easier for the function signature to have only one variable .

Comment: also it's stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: Did you feed it with a properly formed list (where the last element has next = NULL)?  It works perfectly fine for me.

I think using std::swap is clearer but you can do that part without calling an external function (just say `node *t = head->next; head->next = prev; return reverseList(t, head);`)

In a doubly linked list you can do it with just one parameter but I don't see how to do that with a singly linked list.

Comment: @WillNess this question was tagged C++ at the time I answered it. To directly answer your question, no, `std::swap` is not part of C. See my other comment for an alternative that doesn't leverage it.

Comment: thanks for the **`C++`** clarification. you mean `node *t = ...`? but this introduces "new variable" which seems to be forbidden by the question title.

Comment: True, it doesn't respect that stipulation. Unclear to me whether that is really what was meant (the question says "doesn't use any new nodes" which is a more sensible restriction). I suppose for pointers one could use the triple-XOR swap if hellbent on no new explicit variables (and happy to ignore the implicit variables created by the compiler during function calls).

Answer (score 1):

Hey guys please find the programs for reverse linked list with and without recursion below

```
LINK *reverse_linked_list_recursion(LINK *head)
{
        LINK *temp;
        if (!head) {
                printf("Empty list\n");
                return head;
        }
        else if (!head->next)
                return head;
        temp = reverse_linked_list_recursion(head->next);
        head->next->next = head;
        head->next = NULL;
        return temp;
}

LINK *reverse_linked_list_without_recursion(LINK *head)
{
        LINK *new, *temp;
        if (!head) {
                printf("No element in the list\n");
                return head;
        }
        else {
                new = head;
                while (head->next) {
                        temp = head->next;
                        head->next = temp->next;
                        temp->next = new;
                        new = temp;
                }
        }
        return new;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the variation on [Óscar López's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12700722/849891) is

```
Node invert(Node list, Node acc) 
{
    if (!list) 
        return acc; 
    return invert(list.next, ((list.next=acc),list));
}
```

The sequence of expressions `(a,b)` returns its last value and is evaluated left-to-right.

***This will only work*** for compilers which guarantee evaluation order of function's arguments as *left-to-right*. If it is *right-to-left*, the arguments to `invert` should be swapped.

If the evaluation order is *nondeterministic*, this will not work. The C standard apparently leaves this order unspecified, but some compilers might have their own way with it. You may know this about your compiler, but it is non-portable, and your compiler may change this in the future too. Writing such code is frowned upon. Maybe that is what your interviewers wanted to hear from you. They like such tricks, and want to see how you respond.

The normal way to control evaluation order is by using temporary variables.